# Showing an hidden element with an opacity-animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I've a `#foo` element hidden, and I need to show it with `zoomIn` css animation (that bring an element from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1`.

This is the code I'm using:

CSS

```
#foo {
  opacity: 0;
  ...
}

// Zoom In animation
@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.zoomIn {
  animation: zoomIn .2s ease-in-out 0s both;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").addClass("zoomIn");
});​
```

With the above code I see the animation and then the `#foo` element disappears again. It doesn't hold the `opacity:1`.
How can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About Keyframes**

In complement to the post of Slugge, I was wondering why you end your animation at `50%`. I think you should end it  at `100%` (especially if you want the `opacity` to stay at `1`).
Or instead of `0% {} 100% {}`, you can use `from {} to {}`.

```
@keyframes zoomIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**About an other solution**

I think it would be easier to just define a `transition` and an "active" class instead of using **Keyframes**.

```
#foo {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}

#foo.active {
  transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").addClass("active");
});​
```

You could add the **transition** the `transform` as well with `transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out, transform 0.2s ease-out;` or with `transition: all 0.2s ease-out;`

Good Luck'

Comment: I took that animation from animate.css library https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/zooming_entrances/zoomIn.css. I also don't understand why they use 50% as end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what happends at the end of the animation, this can be done with "forwards" property of animation-fill-mode, this requires the animation to have an end (can not end on 50%, must end on 100% or from-to) so change:

```
.zoomIn {
    animation: zoomIn .2s ease-in-out 0s both;
}
```

to:

```
.zoomIn {
     animation: zoomIn .2s ease-in-out 0s forwards;
}
```

By using both, you say that the element should both use forwards and backwards, where forwards is the "end" of the animation, and backwards is the "beginning" of the animation. Therefor you will have opacity: 0 and opacity: 1, and apparently the backwards value is the stronger one of the two.

Comment: With forwards it's the same. I see the animation and then the element returns to opacity 0

Comment: Wait, I added to @keyframe the 100% step with opacity: 1 (holding both in the animation) and now it works... I'm on Chrome. You too? It could be a Chrome bug

Comment: It works for me with my method: http://jsfiddle.net/u03pzjky/ and also, i see now you use 50%, the keyframe needs to have an end (100% or to) updated my answer

Comment: That's it, check my previous comment: the problem here was that was missing the 100% in @keyframe. I took that animation from animate.css library https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/zooming_entrances/zoomIn.css.